cookie set for internal top level domain won't apply for subdomains
If it is not clear I am operating in an intetnal network.
It's looks like when setting a cookie for an internal top level domain it wont apply for any of its subdomains.
I have a site at https://internal and where I set a cookie using JS at client side
document.cookie = `token=<token>;domain=.internal;path=/;secure;SameSite=None`

It appears mostly as set in the dev tools, but the domain is set for "internal" and not ".internal"
When browsing to https://test.internal (or any https://*.internal) the cookie cannot be accessed.
Any idea why? I can't change the URLs of the sites.

Typically wildcard cookies that work at the top won't show up on subdomains. Plus cookies typically cannot be set for the TLD (even fake ones).  I strongly recommend not relying on wildcard cookies at all if possible.
